# What encoding Win32 API functions expect?

Tags: unicode, encoding, winapi

For example, MessageBox function has LPCTSTR typed argument for text and caption, which is a pointer to char or pointer to wchar when _UNICODE or _MBCS are defined, respectively.

How does the MessageBox function interpret those stings? As which encoding?

Only explanation I managed to find is this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cwe8bzh0(VS.90).aspx

But it doesn't say anything about encoding? Just that in case of _MBCS one character takes up one wchar (which is 16-bit on Windows) and that in case of _UNICODE one or two char's (8-bit).

So are those some Microsoft's versions of UTF-8 and UTF-16 that ignore anything that has to be encoded in 3 or four bytes in case of UTF-8 and anything that has to be encoded in 4 bytes in case of UTF-16? And is there a way to show anything outside of basic multilingual plane of Unicode with MessageBox?

Comment: The correct macro is `UNICODE`, not `_UNICODE`. The latter influences the C standard library headers, the former the Windows headers.

Comment: I didn't know that. I did some reading about and I understand the difference now. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are normally two different implementations of each function:

- `MessageBoxA`, which accepts ANSI strings
- `MessageBoxW`, which accepts Unicode strings

Here, 'ANSI' means the multi-byte code page currently assigned to the process. This varies according to the user's preferences and locale setting, although Win32 API functions such as `WideCharToMultiByte` can be counted on to do the right conversion, and the `GetACP` function will tell you the code page in use. [MSDN explains the ANSI code page and how it interacts with Unicode.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317752.aspx)

'Unicode' generally means UCS-2; that is, support for characters above 0xFFFF isn't consistent. I haven't tried this, but UI functions such as `MessageBox` in recent versions (> Windows 2000) should support characters outside the BMP.

Comment: All Unicode API functions in Win2k and later indeed expect UTF-16, not UCS-2.

Answer (score 4):

The `...A` functions are obsolete and only wrap the `...W` functions. The former were required for compatibility with Windows 9x, but since that is not used any more, you should avoid them at any costs and use the `...W` functions exclusively. They require UTF-16 strings, the only native Windows encoding. All modern Windows versions should support non-BMP characters quite well (if there is a font that has these characters, of course).

Comment: The `*A` functions are distinct from the `*W` functions, and expect character strings in a specific code page (and are finally starting to allow the UTF-8 "page").  It's the unadorned ones (like `MessageBox`) that map to either `A` or `W` versions.