# What is the difference between the `A` and `W` functions in the Win32 API?

Tags: winapi, unicode, ascii

What is the difference in calling the Win32 API function that have an `A` character appended to the end as opposed to the `W` character.

I know it means `ASCII` and `WIDE CHARACTER` or Unicode, but what is the difference in the output or the input?

For example, If I call GetDefaultCommConfigA, will it fill my COMMCONFIG structure with ASCII strings instead of WCHAR strings?  (Or vice-versa for GetDefaultCommConfigW)

In other words, how do I know what Encoding the string is in, ASCII or UNICODE, it *must* be by the version of the function I call `A` or `W`? Correct?

I have found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143110/what-encoding-win32-api-functions-expect), but I don't think it answers my question.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The `A` functions use Ansi (not ASCII) strings as input and output, and the `W` functions use Unicode string instead (UCS-2 on NT4 and earlier, UTF-16 on W2K and later).  [Refer to MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/working-with-strings) for more details.

Comment: +1 - also another thing to keep in mind is that all the structures that are passed as parameters to these also come in A and W versions; so for example RegisterClassExA takes a WNDCLASSEXA which uses ANSI LPCSTRs, and while the W versions use LPCWSTRs - this prevents you from passing WCHARs to the A version, and vice versa - if you try, you'll get a compiler error about the types not matching - a fairly common beginner error is to use a cast to make the error "go away" instead of changing the code to use the right type without a cast.

Comment: How does the function without "A" or "W" postfix work? Say "GetVolumeInformation" function, does it call the GetVolumeInformationA or GetVolumeInformationW?

Comment: @yuquan kind of. The non-A/W functions are implemented as preprocessor macros that map to the appropriate A/W functions. They do not *call* the A/W functions, but rather are *replaced* with them during the preprocessor stage, depending on whether `UNICODE` is defined or not. So, for example, if `UNICODE` is defined, a call to `GetVolumeInformation()` is replaced with a call to `GetVolumeInformationW()`, otherwise it is replaced with a call to `GetVolumeInformationA()`.

Comment: That macro substitution "feature" is a real pain.  If you have your own class function called `GetVolumeInformation` it will be silently renamed to `GetVolumeInformationA` or `GetVolumeInformationW`.  Using the IDE to look up the definition will take you to the macro definition, not the function.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yup, and all because Microsoft won't get with the times and support C++ properly, such as by using function overloads and/or template functions rather than the preprocessor.

Comment: To be fair the Win32 API still has to work from C, especially back when wide-char support was first introduced, so a C++ only solution wasn't possible.  But at this point there's no excuse for not creating something better and giving you a way of opting out of the macros.

Comment: @MarkRansom "*the Win32 API still has to work from C*" - yes, but that doesn't mean it can't use proper wrappers for C++. It already does that for COM interfaces, so there is no reason why it can't do that for functions, too.

Comment: I think we're in agreement.

Comment: What are ExA and ExW functions? What's the difference between these all?

Comment: @Shayan The link in my answer, and earlier comments above, explain the `A`/`W` semantics.  Those apply to `ExA`/`ExW` functions as well, which are usually just "Ex"-tended versions of earlier `A`/`W` functions.