# Including header file fileapi.h won't include all contents that exists on microsoft.com

Tags: c++, windows, linker

I am a C++ rookie, so this might be obvious.

I am trying to write a program that prints disk information. While browsing the [`fileapi.h`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/) header file on microsoft.com, I found an interesting function [`GetDiskSpaceInformationA()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getdiskspaceinformationa), which I would like to use.

I created a new C++ console project in Visual Studios 2013, and included `<windows.h>` and `<fileapi.h>`, see whole program below. Now, I noticed that a lot of functions in `fileapi.h` seem to not be included. At least, compared to the functions that are on the website. One of these missing functions is, of course, `GetDiskSpaceInformationA()`.

What is the reason for this? Is it because my target architecture is Windows? Is there anyway for me to get access to the functions I want in `fileapi.h`?

```cpp
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <windows.h>
#include <fileapi.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    GetDiskSpaceInformationA();  //Error identifier "GetDiskSpaceInformationA" is undefined
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You probably want [GetDiskSpaceInformationW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getdiskspaceinformationw). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424383/what-is-the-difference-between-the-a-and-w-functions-in-the-win32-api) as to why.

Comment: @Rex I see, thanks! However, that method can't be found either.

Comment: Perhaps it's been added during the decade that's passed since your Visual Studio was modern.

Comment: if the function exists in fileapi.h then it is probably preprocessorly conditioned. Many WinApi functions depend on which windows version you target.

Comment: BTW ,Since you're a Rookie ,you'd be better off by installing a more modern version of Visual Studio.